# How to resolve dependencies in PNPM workspace?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have a pnpm workspace with the following structure:

```
root
|- example
|  |- package.json
|
|- packages
|  |- a
|  |  |- package.json
|  |
|  |- b
|  |  |- package.json
|  |  
|  |- c
|  |  |- package.json
```

The package `c` is a package that should contain `a` and `b`:

```json
{
  "name": "c",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "workspace:*",
    "b": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

`package.json` file in `example` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "example",
  "dependencies": {
    "c": "workspace:*"
  }
}
```

When I do `pnpm install` it places only `c` dependency in `example/node_modules` - it does not install necessary packages `a` and `b`.

What do I have to do to have all nested dependencies installed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

They are installed correctly. The `c` inside `root/example/node_modules` is a symlink to `root/packages/c`. The dependencies of `c` are symlinked to `root/packages/c/node_modules`.

Answer (score 0):

> When I do pnpm install it places only c dependency in example/node_modules - it does not install necessary packages a and b.

That's the default and intended behavior of node_modules with pnpm. This [article](https://www.kochan.io/nodejs/pnpms-strictness-helps-to-avoid-silly-bugs.html) explains it better